# c# Get URL of the new page after invoking click in Web Browser

Tags: c#, console-application, webbrowser-control

I have to navigate through some pages with an Application Console in C#, I have a known URL as a starting page, but other URLs are not known, I reach them by clicking on buttons in the starting page.
This is the code of the button I need to click on the page:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btn_invia" type="button" id="myId" onclick="ReDirect();" class="myClass" value="BUTTON TEXT" />
```

I tried this code to navigate to the start page, and it works:

```
class Program
{
  private static WebBrowser wb1 = new WebBrowser();

  [STAThread]
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    runBrowserThread(new Uri("http://www.myUrl.com"));
  }

  private static void runBrowserThread(Uri url)
  {
    var th = new Thread(() => {
        var br = new WebBrowser();
        br.DocumentCompleted += Br_DocumentCompleted; ;
        br.Navigate(url);
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
  }

  private static void Br_DocumentCompleted(object sender, 
  WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
  {
    //Retrieve string content of document
    var document = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
    var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = 
    (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;
    var content = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;

    //Parse content with html agility pack or whatever

    //Click on button
    wb1.Document.GetElementById("myId").InvokeMember("click");

    Application.ExitThread();
  }
}
```

When I click on the button, it loads a new page.
But when I call `.InvokeMember("click");` it freezes, how can I make the WebBrowser wb1 go to the new page?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where I was wrong, I called `wb1.Document.GetElementById("myId").InvokeMember("click");` but wb1 wasn't initalized, so I didn't call `.InvokeMember("click")` on an existing element. I modified in this way:

```
((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementById("myId").InvokeMember("Click");
```

in the `Br_DocumentCompleted` method, and now it works. But now I have another problem: I modified the `Br_DocumentCompleted` method in this way, because I have to click on a button in the new page, to open a third page:

```
    private static void Br_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve string content of document
        var document = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document;
        var documentAsIHtmlDocument3 = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)document.DomDocument;
        var content = documentAsIHtmlDocument3.documentElement.innerHTML;

        if (((WebBrowser)sender).Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("startpage.aspx")) 
        {


            //Click on button
            ((WebBrowser)sender).ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementById("myId").InvokeMember("Click");
        }
        else if (((WebBrowser)sender).Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("page1.aspx")) 
        {
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementById("btn_send").InvokeMember("Click");
        }
        else if (((WebBrowser)sender).Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("page2.aspx")) 
        {
            //Some code
            Application.ExitThread();
        }   
    }
```

And the "btn_send" on the page1 has this code:

```
<input onclick="openEVERFANCY('#CChildren','N'); return false;" id=btn_send class=buttonVerifyDisp type=button value=GO>
```

and when I call `((WebBrowser)sender).Document.GetElementById("btn_send").InvokeMember("Click");` on this button, it doesn't go to the third page, even if I have the DocumentCompleted event handler